# read and display a local text file in jsp page

Tags: file, jsp

I would like to read and display a text file in a `JSP` page. I found no error in my code but it display a blank after I run it. I have code like this :

```
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStreamReader"%>
<%@page import="java.net.URL"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Read Text</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String jspPath = "C:\\log\\";
            String fileName = "log.txt";
            String txtFilePath = jspPath + fileName;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFilePath));
            //BufferedReader br = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(txtFilePath));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString()); 
        %>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any exception in the logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send text with the response to user's web browser use:

```
out.println(sb.toString());
```

because

```
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

will send it to Tomcat's log, not to the user.

Comment: yes. @mike_m ...it's worked, seem like i wrote extra on it. Thanks a lot.