# Check image exists in JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to check an image if it exists in JSP level. Like if

```
<s:if test="%{#bankProductType}_HL.png">
    <s:set var="bankProductType" value="${bankName}%{'ICICI_BANK_HL'}"/>
 </s:if>
```

But, it doesn't run. I'm just trying to find if a image of name like ICICI_BANK_HL.png exists.. go into that condition.. Is there anything that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BufferedReader and check for a FileNotFoundException.

example: [Read and display a local text file in jsp page has Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583912/read-and-display-a-local-text-file-in-jsp-page-has-error)

Then wrap

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jspPath));
```

in a try...catch block.

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jspPath));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //code here
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further with some snippet?

Comment: Thanks.. But how can I check if its boolean value or not?

Comment: if the code reaches the catch block then the file wasn't found. that is how the BufferedReader class works, redesign your code to take this into consideration. If need be have a boolean set to false outside the try...catch and set it to true inside the catch.